# floating time error using iCalendar

Tags: c#, outlook, icalendar

I have created the following ICS file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//ddaysoftware.com//NONSGML DDay.iCal 1.0//EN
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Romance Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:20151002T030000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYHOUR=3;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=10
TZNAME:Paris\, Madrid
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
TZOFFSETTO:+0100
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20150301T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=-1SU;BYHOUR=2;BYMINUTE=0;BYMONTH=3
TZNAME:Paris\, Madrid (heure d’été)
TZOFFSETFROM:+0100
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:ACCESS initiation
DTEND:20160810T170000
DTSTAMP:20160426T073625Z
DTSTART:20160810T090000
LOCATION:Bruxelles Formation
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY: ACCESS initiation
UID:acd169c5-7cce-4085-b0bb-88b25bc6fd46
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:ACCESS initiation
DTEND:20160811T170000
DTSTAMP:20160426T073625Z
DTSTART:20160811T090000
LOCATION:Formation
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:ACCESS initiation
UID:8c7f3bd0-6cad-41df-943c-ed42a1ea6ca0
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DESCRIPTION:ACCESS initiation
DTEND:20160812T170000
DTSTAMP:20160426T073625Z
DTSTART:20160812T090000
LOCATION:Bruxelles Formation
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY: ACCESS initiation
UID:32409720-95a8-4f79-b788-77f707ff8002
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And as far as I understand I should add the "Z" in the end of each date DTEND and DTSTART. I did that but then in Outlook I don't have any error message but all the times are 2 hours later than what it should be.

This is the code :

```
DDay.iCal.iCalendar iCal = new DDay.iCal.iCalendar();
iCal.AddLocalTimeZone();
evt.Start = new iCalDateTime(tempStart);
evt.End = new iCalDateTime(tempEnd);                
evt.Start.IsUniversalTime = true; //gives the Z in the end of the date
evt.End.IsUniversalTime = true;
```

How can I fix the 2 hours difference?

Answer (score 0):

"Z" stands for universal time or UTC.

You have the following line in your definition:

```
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
```

This means that your local times are 2 hours ahead of UTC. Adding a the "Z" means that the times are treated as UTC times so are 2 hours different to what you expect.

Simply have:

```
evt.Start.IsUniversalTime = false;
evt.End.IsUniversalTime = false;
```

and the times should be what you expect.

Another approach is to convert all your times to UTC before saving:

```
evt.Start = evt.Start.ToUniversalTime();
evt.End = evt.End.ToUniversalTime();
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then the times will be UTC though you'll need to convert back from UTC when displaying as a local time.

Comment: I tried that, the result is the date without the Z in the end and Outlook error      floating time...

Comment: I found a solution. I had to add TZID to both DTEND and DTSTART, in my case I added "Romance Standard".